# Case expression gives "conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table and table data. After which when I execute the select statement using cases, then I am getting error

> The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

But when I comment my second case then select works fine. Please help me to understand this issue

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
ID varchar(20),
T_Date date,
FLAG varchar(20)
);

insert into TEST values('1234', '0001-01-01', NULL);

select t.T_Date, t.FLAG,
CASE
    WHEN t.FLAG IS NULL AND t.T_Date IS NOT NULL AND t.T_Date != '2001-01-01' THEN t.T_Date
    WHEN t.FLAG IS NULL AND (t.T_Date IS NULL OR (t.T_Date IS NOT NULL AND t.T_Date = '2001-01-01')) THEN CONVERT(datetime, '20201216', 112) + 10
END as t_date
FROM TEST t
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **every** branch of a `case` expression **must** return the same datatype. So with your convert to `datetime` in the second branch you forced SQL Server to try and convert your first branch to `datetime` also due to [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

And when, in the first branch, you try and convert your `date` value, "0001-01-01", to `datetime` it fails, because the lowest value `datetime` can handle is ["January 1, 1753"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You also cannot add 10 to a `date`, nor should you, even though `datetime` allows it. What are you adding? Days? Hours? Minutes? Use the `dateadd` function to correctly add to a `date`.

```
SELECT t.T_Date, t.FLAG,
    CASE
    WHEN t.FLAG IS NULL AND t.T_Date IS NOT NULL AND t.T_Date != '2001-01-01' THEN t.T_Date
    WHEN t.FLAG IS NULL AND (t.T_Date IS NULL OR (t.T_Date IS NOT NULL AND t.T_Date = '2001-01-01')) THEN DATEADD(DAY, 10, CONVERT(DATE, '20201216', 112))
    END AS t_date
FROM #TEST t
```

Comment: Thanks Dale. But we are not converting '0001-01-01', it's '20201216'. How this is causing the failure?

Comment: @shalabh as mentioned, **all** branches of the `case` are now being evaluated to `datetime` instead of `date` and your first branch results in `THEN t.T_Date` the value of which is '0001-01-01'. In your example the first branch attempts to return a result by converting it to datetime which fails.

Comment: Got it now @Dale. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression has to produce a value of one fixed type, no matter which clause ends up matching.

`datetime` has a [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than `date`, and is therefore the type of your `CASE` expression.

A `datetime` is incapable of storing a date before 1753. Your `date` value is in the year 1.

As [suggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (for at least a decade):

> Use the `time`, `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` data types for new work.

```
select t.T_Date, t.FLAG,
CASE
    WHEN t.FLAG IS NULL AND t.T_Date IS NOT NULL AND t.T_Date != '2001-01-01'
       THEN t.T_Date
    WHEN t.FLAG IS NULL AND (t.T_Date IS NULL OR (t.T_Date IS NOT NULL AND t.T_Date = '2001-01-01'))
       THEN CONVERT(date, '20201226', 112)
END as t_date
FROM TEST t
```

Comment: But we are not converting '0001-01-01', it's '20201216'. How this is causing the failure?

Comment: Understood now @Damien. Thanks